# Save null foreign key

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

When i save my object, all saved good except field of foreign key.
My models:

```
public class Persons{
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    }

public class Notes{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Persons Owner { get; set; }
        public virtual string Head { get; set; }
        public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

My mapping:

```
public class PersonsMap : ClassMap<Persons>{
    public PersonsMap(){
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        Table("Persons");
    }
}

public class NotesMap: ClassMap<Notes>{
    public NotesMap(){
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Head);
        Map(x => x.Text);
        HasOne(x => x.Owner);
        Table("Notes");
    }        
}
```

My code:

```
public void CreateNote(int id, Notes note){
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()){
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()){
                note.Owner = session.QueryOver<Persons>().Where(x => x.Id ==     
                id).SingleOrDefault();   // note.Owner = {Id = 1; Name = "Name";           
                                         // Password = "Password"}
                session.Save(note);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Operation result is succes but:

Id is 2, Owner is null, Head is "Some head", Text is "Some text"

Why is owner null? What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your mappings are incorrect.  The relationship between notes and person is not a one to one.  They don't share a primary key.

http://www.jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/

```
public class NotesMap: ClassMap<Notes>{
    public NotesMap(){
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Head);
        Map(x => x.Text);

        References(x => x.Owner)
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

        Table("Notes");
    }        
}
```

Also when you just need to set a relationship up you don't need to actually query the database to do so when you know the id.  Use session.Load to save a query.

```
note.Owner = session.Load<Persons>(id);
```